# Apache camel: aggregate by qualifier from log

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have a simple log example:

```
2017-02-02 09:58:12,764 - INFO - PRC0XK - logged in
2017-02-02 09:58:13,766 - INFO - L3J5WW - logged in
2017-02-02 09:58:14,005 - INFO - 0NKCVZ - call s2
2017-02-02 09:58:14,767 - INFO - P0QIOW - logged in
2017-02-02 09:58:15,729 - INFO - E0MVFZ - call s2
2017-02-02 09:58:16,257 - INFO - L3J5WW - call s2
2017-02-02 09:58:17,750 - INFO - PRC0XK - call s2
2017-02-02 09:58:21,908 - INFO - P0QIOW - call s2
2017-02-02 09:58:30,479 - INFO - PRC0XK - get answer from s2
2017-02-02 09:58:30,479 - INFO - PRC0XK - logged out
```

It's formed by fields like `"{timestamp} - {LogLevel} - {USERID} - {Action}"`.
I want to use it as input and forming the actions one by one by `USERID`.
Later, I wish to add an another log file formed in the same way, which also have the simple modified `USERID`, and collect all actions through two logs together by `USERID`.
I try to use aggregation strategy, but i've got some that i not expect.
My camel route is:

```
<route id="fileeater">
<description>
    this route will eat log file and try to put guid through lot of log entry by some identifier
</description>
<from uri="file://data/in?charset=utf-8"/>
<split streaming="true">
    <tokenize token="\n"/>
    <to uri="log:gotlogline"/>
    <aggregate strategyRef="SimpleAggregationStrategy" completionSize="4">
        <correlationExpression>
          <constant>true</constant>
        </correlationExpression>
        <log logName="LOGEater" message="this is logeater part"/>
        <to uri="file://data/out"/>
    </aggregate>
</split>
```

where SimpleAggregationStrategy is:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;

public class SimpleAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy{

@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {

    if(oldExchange == null) {
        return newExchange;
    }

    String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String body= oldBody;
    if (oldBody.split(" - ")[2].equalsIgnoreCase(newBody.split(" - ")[2])){
        body = oldBody + "\n" + newBody;
    }

    oldExchange.getIn().setBody(body);

    return oldExchange;
}

}
```

So, I expect entries logged and grouped by `USERID`:

```
...
2017-02-02 09:59:45,599 - INFO - NU7444 - logged in 
2017-02-02 09:59:51,229 - INFO - NU7444 - call s2
2017-02-02 10:00:09,818 - INFO - NU7444 - get answer from s2
2017-02-02 10:00:09,818 - INFO - NU7444 - logged out
...
```

But I've got only two lines in outfile:

```
2017-02-02 10:00:09,818 - INFO - NU7444 - get answer from s2
2017-02-02 10:00:09,818 - INFO - NU7444 - logged out
```

My thoughts is about correlationExpression in aggregation:

1. can I use part of log line (split(" - ")[2] as `USERID`) to bind it together by aggregation?
2. I read http://www.catify.com/2012/07/09/parsing-large-files-with-apache-camel/ and found that aggregation by header is faster than simple aggregation. So, can i use the part of line after splitting as a header, and then collect it in aggregation by header? Should i use Processor to get part of line(`USERID`) and put it in a header for it?

Comment: well, i add a processor which fill header for each line: `public class UserIDProcessor implements Processor{
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  String input = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
     if (input.split(" - ").length > 2){
      exchange.getIn().setHeader("LOGLEVEL", input.split(" - ")[1]);
      exchange.getIn().setHeader("USERID", input.split(" - ")[2]);
     }
     exchange.getIn().setBody(input);
 }
` and made aggregation by header. But i still have output only for one USERID, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, guys. Seems like i found a solution after playing with camel.
it's about using a process which can set a header for each log entry like i mention in comment:

```
public class UserIDProcessor implements Processor{
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String input = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        if (input.split(" - ").length > 2){
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("LOGLEVEL", input.split(" - ")[1]);
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("USERID", input.split(" - ")[2]);
        }
        exchange.getIn().setBody(input);
    }
}
```

Then, i aggregate messages by header using simple aggrstrategy:

```
public class SimpleAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy{
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        if(oldExchange == null) {
            return newExchange;
        }
        String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String body= oldBody + "\r\n" + newBody;
        oldExchange.getIn().setBody(body);
        return oldExchange;
    }
}
```

And use quite simple route (you can add timeout flag and completion size in aggregation route part base on your needs):

```
<route id="fileeater">
    <description>
        this route will eat log file and try to put guid through lot of log entry by some identifier
    </description>
    <from uri="file://data/in?charset=utf-8&amp;delete=false&amp;readLock=idempotent-changed&amp;readLockCheckInterval=5000"/>
    <split streaming="true">
        <tokenize token="\n"/>
        <process ref="UIDProcessor"/>
        <aggregate strategyRef="SimpleAggregationStrategy" completionSize="4">
            <correlationExpression>
              <simple>header.USERID</simple>
            </correlationExpression>
            <to uri="log:gotlogline"/>
            <to uri="file://data/out?fileExist=append"/>
        </aggregate>
    </split>
</route>
```

Also, to increase parsing speed you can add an `parallelProcessing="true"` flag to split and got an extrimely fast result.